# How to check if one2many field is empty in openerp xml views

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7, erp

I'm trying to make some field invisible if another field ( which is one2many ) has no value ( is empty).

I'm trying something like

```
<field name="reference" invisible="{'line_ids', '=', False}"/>
```

Also tried

```
<field name="reference" invisible="{'line_ids', 'in', []}"/>
```

And finally

```
<field name="reference" invisible="{'line_ids', '=', None}"/>
```

*Note: line_ids is one2many field*

But did not work. Somebody please suggest if some possible way to do this.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 16):

Try following,

```
<field name="reference" attrs="{'invisible' :[('line_ids', '=', False)]}"/>
```

This is the behaviour of attrs in odoo, version by  version it's differ.

[image]

Comment: The empty list `('something_ids', '!=', [])` works for required by Many2many in Odoo 13, False or tuple don't seem to.

Answer (score 6):

For a One2many field in Odoo 10, I have just tested myself and an empty list works, as in:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('item_ids', '=', [])]}"
```

I have heard from other people that the above works for Odoo 9 as well. For Odoo 8 I've also used:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('item_ids', '=', [(6, False, [])])]}"
```

...with success. If any of these are not working for you and your respective version, try updating your source. Also, for Odoo 7 the empty list way should work (but I haven't tried it myself). It's kinda weird how they went from [] to [(6, False, [])])] and then back to [].

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I tried with Emipro's solutions, but doesn't work (but you still must use "attrs" instead of invisible).

Also, I tried with

```
[('line_ids', '=', [(0, 0, [])])]
```

and

```
[('line_ids', '=', [(6, False, [])])]
```

but nothing worked.

In the end, I ended up creating a boolean computed field

```
self.line_count = len(self.line_ids) > 0
```

and it works with the simpler condition

```
[('line_count', '=', False)]
```

if anybody would suggest the correct solution....

Comment: your approach is correct, we cannot change fields behaviour based on one2many fields as they wont be stored in corresponding table

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
<field name="reference" attrs="{'invisible' :[('line_ids', '!=', [])]}"/>
```

Comment: I would double check that, in the case of Odoo 10, 9 and 7 you created a condition that the field will be invisible whenever line_ids is NOT empty and in the case of Odoo 8, you created a condition that will always be True and therefore the field will never be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. This one worked for me

```
<field name="reference" attrs="{'invisible': [('line_ids', '=', [(6, False, [])])]}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[('line_ids', '=', [[6, False, []]])]

It works for me in openerp7